# Como sumar 2 columnas por calendario en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero realizar la suma de `sueldo1` y `sueldo 2`, utilice `SUM();` pero eso me hace sumar las dos columnas pero en todos los calendarios.

¿hay alguna forma de realizar la suma de ambas columnas pero por calendario?

Es decir, que se sumen las 2 columnas del calendario 7 y me de un `Total` por calendario. Y así sucesivamente para todos los calendarios o ¿hay alguna alternativa para hacer esas sumas desde `PHP` y evitar hacerlo en `MySQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que estas buscando algo asi

```
SELECT SUM(SUELDO1 + SUELDO2)
FROM TABLA
GROUP BY CALENDARIOS_ID
```

O si queres cada columna por separado seria

```
SELECT SUM(SUELDO1),
SUM(SUELDO2)
FROM TABLA
GROUP BY CALENDARIOS_ID
```

y podrias agregar una clausula where si solo quieres ver los de un id particular

```
WHERE
CALENDARIOS_ID = 7
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en cuanto pasen los 8 minutos acepto tu respuesta y -_- nunca recordé que se podía realizar por grupos.

Answer (score 0):

Suma de columnas sueldo1 y sueldo2 agrupado por calendarios_id

```
select calendarios_id, sum(sueldo1), sum(sueldo2) 
    from tabla 
      group by 1 
      order by 1;
```